# Nested Template Strings/Literals Error: Missing }

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, template-strings

I am trying to make a nav bar using information pulled from the DOM, but I keep getting an error associated ES6 template strings (nested in this case) that reads **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression"**

I'm pretty new to ES6 syntax. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
function makeNavList() {
var myList = ``;

$("#superfish-1>li").each(function (index, value) {

    myList += `<li>
    <a href="#!">${$(value).find(">a").text()}</a>

    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
    <li><a href="${$(value).find("a").attr("href")}">${$(value).find(">a").text()} - All</a></li>
    ${
        let collapselist= () =>{ 
            let innerlist = "";
            $("#superfish-1>li.ul>li").each(function(index, value){
                let linkPath = $(value).find("a").attr("href");
                let linkText = $(value).find("a").text();
                innerlist += `<li>
                <a href="${linkPath}">${linkText}</a>
                </li>`
            })
            return innerlist;
        }

    }</ul>
    </li>`

})
return myList
}
```

Comment: I don't know ES6 but are you sure that your are missing a `}` somewhere?  It seems to suggest that from the error.

Comment: You can not declare a variable inside `${}`

Comment: `${}` can only contain expressions, not statements.

Comment: You're trying to do way too much in a template lateral. Move it out to a function and have the literal invoke the function. Even if that was a single, valid expression, it's still just too much for sanity's sake.

Comment: Yes! Moving the function declaration outside of the template literal did the trick! Although maybe we should be allowed to have statements up in there.. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your function outside the template. You can not declare statements inside `${}`:

```
function makeNavList() {
var myList = ``;

$("#superfish-1>li").each(function (index, value) {

    myList += `<li>
    <a href="#!">${$(value).find(">a").text()}</a>

    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
    <li><a href="${$(value).find("a").attr("href")}">${$(value).find(">a").text()} - All</a></li>
    ${getCollapselist()}</ul>
    </li>`

})
return myList
}

getCollapselist = function(){
  let innerlist = "";
  $("#superfish-1>li.ul>li").each(function(index, value){
      let linkPath = $(value).find("a").attr("href");
      let linkText = $(value).find("a").text();
      innerlist += `<li>
      <a href="${linkPath}">${linkText}</a>
      </li>`
  })
  return innerlist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of a token placeholder in a template literal must be an *expression*, but you're trying to use a *statement* (`let collapselist = ...`). You can't do that.

Instead, it's probably cleanest to create the list first and then embed it in the string:

```
let collapselist= () =>{ 
    let innerlist = "";
    $("#superfish-1>li.ul>li").each(function(index, value){
        let linkPath = $(value).find("a").attr("href");
        let linkText = $(value).find("a").text();
        innerlist += `<li>
        <a href="${linkPath}">${linkText}</a>
        </li>`
    })
    return innerlist;
};
```

then

```
${collapelist}
```

...in the template literal.

Answer (score -1):

if you have ES6 features you need to standarize your code with the new good practices of ES6 features, for example the use of arrow functions etc, Your error was that you declare your function inside {}.

```
const makeNavList = () => {
    let myList = '';

    const collapseList = () =>{ 
        let innerList = '';
        $("#superfish-1>li.ul>li").each(value => {
            const linkPath = $(value).find("a").attr("href");
            const linkText = $(value).find("a").text();
            innerList += `<li><a href="${linkPath}">${linkText}</a></li>`
        });

        return innerList;
    }

    $("#superfish-1>li").each(value => {

        myList += `<li>
        <a href="#!">${$(value).find(">a").text()}</a>

        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="${$(value).find("a").attr("href")}">${$(value).find(">a").text()} - All</a></li>
            ${`${collapseList()}`} 
        </ul>
        </li>`

    })

    return myList
}
```